# Wordpress randomly redirects with 301 after logging in

Tags: php

**Situation**

I'm trying to host 2 Wordpress websites on the same virtual machine.

- Site1: www.mainsite.com
- Site2: site2.mainsite.com

Each site has its own Wordpress installation and database (not multisite).

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nginx 1.17.1
- PHP7.3-FPM
- Certbot for Let's Encrypt
- HSTS activated for domain

**Problem**

After installing both Wordpress websites and logging in on wp-admin. The last one starts redirecting to the other one with a 301 redirect.

Steps to reproduce:

- Clear browser cache
- Visit www.mainsite.com/wp-admin and login
- Visit site2.mainsite.com/wp-admin and login
- Visit www.mainsite.com
- Visit site2.mainsite.com -> Gets redirected to www.mainsite.com with X-Redirect-By: WordPress in the response header

This is not always true, sometimes it works for a few minutes before it starts to redirect. The 301 redirects get cached by the browser, so when the redirect occurs, it never works again unless I manually clear my browser cache.

**Tried solutions**

- Clearing browser cache, tried another computer
- Added WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to both wp-config.php files
- Checked my Nginx server blocks and PHP-pools
- Tried separate SSL certificates with Certbot
- Tried wildcard SSL certificate with Certbot
- Reboot
- Checked both MySQL databases for URLS

---

Do I have to add something in the Wordpress config to stop the redirect?
I think it has something to do with the cookie that got created when logging in.

Comment: Just a comment, but it sounds like the potential solution here is to log out of one site before logging in to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have not set opcache.validate_root=1 in php.ini. It's mandatory for
chrooted php-fpm with multiple pools (and unfortunately not very clearly documented).

RTFM:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-root